# Electron - no log message printed by LOG(INFO) in C++ file

Tags: c++, electron

I downloaded and compiled Electron (https://github.com/electron/electron) from source. I tried to add some lines like LOG(INFO) << "some message" in some .cc file to help understand how the code works. The compiling succeed, but I did not see any messages being printed in the shell.

Could someone advise what I should do to get these messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the [`ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v0.37.8/docs/api/environment-variables.md#electron_enable_logging) environment variable before running Electron.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!